# Article on running greenplum on Ramdisk

Tags: performance, ramdisk, greenplum

Where can I find good articles on running Greenplum on Ramdisk? There are lot of artciles related to running postgres in Ramdisk, But I could not find for Greenplum. Can somebody help?

Comment: You might want to be more specific in terms of what you are trying to do and why so you can get a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of someone running Greenplum DB on a Ramdisk with great success, but I doubt that has been published. The implementation seems pretty straightforward.